# previous state object of onFlushDirty()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How to get the previous state object of an entity in onFlushDirty() method of EmptyInterceptor? I can have the current session and current entity object but getting the previous state for that entity object is not coming up. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can access previous object values using `Object[] previousState and String[] propertyNames` parameters.

```
@Override
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState,
                    Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {

  //Assume SampleBO is your BO class
   if (entity instanceof SampleBO){

    String userName=  previousState[ArrayUtils.indexOf(propertyNames, "userName")].toString();

    //Do what ever you want with values

   ((SampleBO)entity).setUserName(userName);

}
}
```

I have used this for my BO audit purposes in there i just fetch the object difference between `previousState`  and `currentState` as a Json obj.

**class ObjectDiffVo**

```
class ObjectDiffVo{

   propertyName;
   oldValue;
   newValue;

//getter and setters
}
```

**CompareObjDiff function**

```
private List<ObjectDiffVo> compareObjDiff(Object[] currentState,
            Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames) {

        List<ObjectDiffVo> odVoL = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {

            if (previousState[i] != currentState[i]) {

                ObjectDiffVo odVo = new ObjectDiffVo();
                odVo.setPropertyName(propertyNames[i]);
                odVo.setOldValue(previousState[i]);
                odVo.setNewValue(currentState[i]);
                odVoL.add(odVo);
            }

        }

        return odVoL;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.