# Capture generated SQL from Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a requirement to capture changes to certain data.  I am looking to capture the following details:

1. Table Name the change occurred in
2. Column Changed
3. Previous Value
4. Updated Value

I suggested to our Technical lead that this can be accomplished easily with DB Triggers. I was told we do not control the DB and do not have a way of adding Triggers.

I am currently using Spring AspectJ with a custom annotation and wrapping my services to try and capture the generated SQL (I figure parsing SQL is much easier that trying to capture with Objects) that's executed after the 'save' method is called, however I have not found a way to trap the generated SQL.

I tried p6Spy and was able to view the SQL and print it to the console, but was told we cannot wrap our db drivers in our PROD environment.

Is there a Spring class I am missing to make this easier?

EDIT : We're using Spring Repositories to save the data.

EDIT 2:  I'm looking into `EventListener`s, however I cannot seem to get them to listen to my events.

```
@Component
public class EventListner implements PreInserEventListener, PreUpdateEventListener {
   @Override
   @EventListener
   public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event){
     // do something

     return false;
   }

   @Override
   @EventListener
   public boolean onPreInsert(PreUpdateEvent event){
     // do something
   }
   return false
}
```

I have break points around my `Listener`, however they're never reached.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504583/previous-state-object-of-onflushdirty) looks like it might address my issue

Comment: I'm looking into `@EventListeners` to see if I can capture the values there.

Comment: If you don't want to use `envers`, then you can fork envers project to push data where you want. not sure if it is simple or complex, but the process are there (filtering, old value, new value)  and I guess done correctly. (1 entity to backup is ok to do manually, 100 to parametrize, not really)

Comment: Yes, we have the potential to 'audit' 1000's of entities

Comment: Where do you store the changes? Intercepting the SQL isn’t going to help. Also why don’t you control the database? How are table changes managed as you are writing the application.

Comment: The plan was parsing the INSERT and UPDATE statements and persist them in our audit table.  We dont have control b/c it's a managed service, so the triggers would have side effects to other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally settled on using Hibernate interceptors to do the trick.  Works perfectly!

```
public class TableInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

   @Override
   public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id,
                               Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
                               String[] propertyNames, Type[] types){

         // do comparison logic on fields and save to DB
   }
}
```

I bootstrapped the interceptor injecting it into my `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that every insert/update/delete is done through JPA without any bulk SQL then you should take a look at [`envers`](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/)

With that you can use `@Audited` on the entities(all column) OR columns of entities you wish to keep history.

This will create 1 revision table with timestamp change (and other data you want like uid of the user that made the change), and 1 table per entity with the old value of the modified data.

For every data you can then retrieve the history and previous value.

one other way is to add instrument on your DB like a Change Data Capture (CDC) tools and push those event to another data repository. 
On the + side everything will be detected (even native SQL run directly on the DB). Drawback, your DB need to support this kind of tools correctly. For instance tools like [kafka-connect](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) can work like you want, but some implementations are too simple (like with SAP hana for instance where the process is to do a `select * from xxx`).

Comment: We looked into that, however creating a shadow of every table we're auditing is not something our management wants to do.